# The rest of the inputs become invalid

Tags: java

So I got this code to check if the input is an int or not:

```
    public static int getInt(){
    boolean bool = true;
    int answerInt = 0;
    while(bool == true){
        try{
            answerInt = sc.nextInt();
            bool = false;
        }catch(InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Error");
            break;

        }
    }
    return answerInt;
}
```

So if the user enter something invalid then the rest of the inputs in the program become "null". Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: **Never** test `boolean` values against `true` or `false`. This is ugly and error prone. Write `while(bool)`.

Comment: What are "the rest of the inputs in the program"?  It's not clear at all what you're asking.

Comment: @David So i get 2 numbers, both through this getInt() method. Then I have a method that returns a String value, but when i enter something invalid here, then the program just gets "null" everywhere where i got a .nextInt, .nextString...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static int getInt() {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean bool = true;
    int answerInt = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter an int");

    while (bool) {
        try {
            answerInt = sc.nextInt();
            bool = false;
            sc.close(); 
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Try again");
            sc.next(); //Can you figure out why this line is needed?
        }

    }

    return answerInt;

}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can add to your answer what you changed and why you changed it?